# How can I close alert message by enter action through keyboard?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I'm looking for a different way to close an alert message other than `accept()` or `dismiss()` methods. How can I close an alert message by entering action through the keyboard?

Comment: Why? What is the context? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your exact requirements in your software testing services but from question it seems you want to perform Enter key action through keyboard on a javascript popup. TO accomplish this use following code:

```
Alert alert = new Alert();
alert.sendkeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

or

```
alert.sendkeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

If that doesn't work you can use Enter key code and pass it to sendkeys, like this

```
alert.sendkeys(<<ENter key code>>);
```

Hope it helps.